# How can I remove specific characters in certain lines in a file?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, cut

How do I cut characters from column 5 to 7 of the lines 3 onwards?

I am trying to use sed/cut.

For example, If I have

```
this is amazing1 this is amazing11
this is amazing2 this is amazing21
this is amazing3 this is amazing31
this is amazing4 this is amazing41
this is amazing5 this is amazing51
this is amazing6 this is amazing61
this is amazing7 this is amazing71
```

Output should look like:

```
this is amazing1 this is amazing11
this is amazing2 this is amazing21
this amazing3 this is amazing31
this amazing4 this is amazing41
this amazing5 this is amazing51
this amazing6 this is amazing61
this amazing7 this is amazing71
```

The characters  `is` are removed from lines 3 and onwards.

Comment: [edit] your question to show an attempt to solve the problem yourself. See [ask].

Comment: Do you really want to cut columns 5-7, or do you want to cut the 2nd space-delimited field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use awk for clarity, portability, etc.:

```
$ awk 'NR>2{$0=substr($0,1,4) substr($0,8)} 1' file
this is amazing1 this is amazing11
this is amazing2 this is amazing21
this amazing3 this is amazing31
this amazing4 this is amazing41
this amazing5 this is amazing51
this amazing6 this is amazing61
this amazing7 this is amazing71
```

or using variables populated with the values from your question:

```
$ awk -v n=3 -v beg=5 -v end=7 'NR>=n{$0=substr($0,1,beg-1) substr($0,end+1)} 1' file
this is amazing1 this is amazing11
this is amazing2 this is amazing21
this amazing3 this is amazing31
this amazing4 this is amazing41
this amazing5 this is amazing51
this amazing6 this is amazing61
this amazing7 this is amazing71
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -E '3,$s/(....).../\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

In two steps:

```sh
head -n2 infile; tail -n+3 infile | cut --complement -c5-7
```

The first command prints the first two lines unmodified; the second command pipes the lines starting with the third one to `cut`, where character 5 to 7 are removed (requires GNU `cut`).

If you need to do something with the output, like store it in a file, you have to group these commands before redirecting:

```sh
{
    head -n2 infile
    tail -n+3 infile | cut --complement -c5-7
} > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `sed`:

```
sed '1,2!s/^\(\w*\)\s*\w*\(.*\)$/\1\2/' file
```

**DETAILS**

- `1,2!s` - Don't do substitutions on line 1 and 2.
- `/^\(\w*\)\s*\w*\(.*\)$/` - The matching pattern.
- `/\1\2/` - Restore the groups of 1 and 2.
- `file` - Your input file.